# Android trouble with listview row XML layout

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout, row

I've got a ListView with a custom adapter, and I'm trying to modify the layout XML for the list item row so that it looks correct.  I'm trying to achieve the following layout (imagine that the below is centered vertically):

```
Icon    Title          >
        Description
```

The problem that I'm running into however is that the Title and Description's are varying lenghts, therefore the ">" icon is pushed more to the right with longer text (and sometimes goes beyond the screen).

I'm trying to get the ">" icon to always be on the far right edge of the screen, and to have any longer text be "capped" with an ellipsis.  I'd prefer to not use a RelativeLayout. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serverName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/chevron" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout to achieve this. Here is an example from android developer blog [LINK](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: Nice link, makes a lot of sense. Swayed me to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: As link says less layout will optimize your UI. And in case of list view it is very necessary to keep in mind.

Comment: +1 and @littleK Yea sure...!! the link also influenced me to change my current application layout...!! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Put your icon in another `LinearLayout`
Just ignore and replace your icon and text colors because it was my formation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5sp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="5">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/news_image" android:layout_height="50sp" android:layout_width="50sp" android:scaleType="center" android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="8sp" android:layout_weight="2">
        <TextView android:text="News Heading" android:id="@+id/news_heading" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="20sp" android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textColor="@color/themePlainBlue"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="News Details" android:id="@+id/news_details" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="5.6">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/news_image" android:layout_height="50sp" android:scaleType="center" android:src="@drawable/list_arrow" android:layout_width="32sp" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```